# Unable to execute Array.prototype.find in IE / Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using this to solve my problem for IE / Edge that does not support [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility)

Below is my piece of code that i am using in my angular directive to find the element from array.

```
var found = scope.data.find(function(element, i) {
    index = i;
    return element.id === testObj.id;
});
```

Here **scope.data** is my json array and **testObj** is some random json which contains required id.

I am getting below error in IE / Edge.

> Object doesn't support property or method 'find'

Any help?

Comment: If it's not a string it isn't [JSON](http://json.org). And there's no "json array". What you have there is an array of objects.

Comment: Just some lines above the compatibility table is a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill). Just use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to find the best solution for me.

I have used [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

It has full support for all the browsers. Now i don't need to use polyfill anymore.

Sample code:

```
var index = -1;
var found = scope.data.comments.some(function(element, i) {
    index = i;
    return element.id === commentObj.previousId;
});
```

Comment: Some will return only true or false. Does not return the matched value.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's not supported with IE and Edge, alternatively you can use use filter instead of find; but filter returns an array of matching objects.

```
scope.data.filter(function (x) {
         return x.id === testObj.id;
    })[0];
```

Comment: Your answer is also correct, But you missed the index ;)

Answer (score 1):

Array.find is not available on IE. You can use filter to achieve this. 
Use fiter and pick the first value.

```
var found = scope.data.filter(function(element, i) {
    index = i;
    return element.id === testObj.id;
})[0]
```

Updated Approach when you want the index of found data:

```
    var foundIndex;
    var found = scope.data.filter(function(element, i) {
        if(!foundIndex && element.id === testObj.id){
            foundIndex = i;
            return true
        }
            return;
        })[0] 
    index = foundIndex
```

Comment: I think the index returned here is different compare to what i was getting in find function. Anything changed?

Comment: I can't user filter here, Because i have seen that filter is creating new array internally so i will not get correct index.

Comment: @JayeshDhandha The index is the one from `scope.data`. And instead of "abusing" `.find()` to get an index just use `.findIndex()` instead (there's also a polyfill)

Comment: Yes index i will be the last index. If you also want the index and don't want to use the polyfill, I have updated the approach.

Comment: Actually we have polyfill for Array.prototype.find as well. But it is not working in my angular code. Any idea?
Ref: https://libraries.io/bower/Array.prototype.find

Comment: @Jayesh, I suggest you to try to make a test with any simple sample code using that polyfil to check and verify that it is working correctly in IE. than it can help to narrow down the issue. than after you can try to implement it in your Angular site.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, I don't what steps i need to follow to use polyfill in my angular app. I installed the polyfill from bower and now i am trying to use directly as before. Is there anything i need to inject in my current angular directive?

Comment: @Ashish, Your updated code is not clear to me. You are defining index variable after using it in filter, And you haven't initialized the foundIndex variable. It is not working for me atleast.

Comment: @JayeshDhandha Corrected It.

Answer (score 1):

You can polyfill `Array.prototype.find` with the following snippet:

```
// https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.find
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'find', {
    value: function(predicate) {
     // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
      }

      var o = Object(this);

      // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
      var len = o.length >>> 0;

      // 3. If IsCallable(predicate) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
      if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
      }

      // 4. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
      var thisArg = arguments[1];

      // 5. Let k be 0.
      var k = 0;

      // 6. Repeat, while k < len
      while (k < len) {
        // a. Let Pk be ! ToString(k).
        // b. Let kValue be ? Get(O, Pk).
        // c. Let testResult be ToBoolean(? Call(predicate, T, « kValue, k, O »)).
        // d. If testResult is true, return kValue.
        var kValue = o[k];
        if (predicate.call(thisArg, kValue, k, o)) {
          return kValue;
        }
        // e. Increase k by 1.
        k++;
      }

      // 7. Return undefined.
      return undefined;
    },
    configurable: true,
    writable: true
  });
}
```

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - array.prototype.find - polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill)

Comment: How can i use this polyfill in my angular app? 
I have installed this polyfill using bower. Is there anything i need to do?
Or how can i use this whole code by manually writing it into some file?